# LaTeX multiple equation references in one

Tags: latex

Is it possible to combine multiple equation references into one, like it is for the \cite command? What I would like is the following:

```
\begin{subequations}
 \begin{align}
  a & = b \label{eq1} \\
  c & = d \label{eq2}
 \end{align}
\end{subequations}

Some text referring to the formulas \eqref{eq1,eq2}.
```

which would then compile as "Some text referring to the formulas (1a,b)." Obviously, this example doesn't work, but I'm hoping there's a package out there that does something similar. Any ideas?

Comment: There is an excellent response to that question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/show-equation-number-only-once-in-align-environment).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [`cleveref`-package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/). [Here](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf)'s documentation.

You can then use `\cref{eq2,eq1,eq3,eq5,thm2,def1}` in order to do it.

Answer (score 48):

This is a simple solution that requires no additional packages, just one additional label:

```
\begin{subequations}
 \label{eq1}
 \begin{align}
  a & = b \label{eq11} \\
  c & = d \label{eq12}
 \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

And when you do `\eqref{eq1}` it will display as (1).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It should be the accepted one as it's the most upvoted one and it solves the problem without any additional packages.

Comment: You can also add `\nonumber` instead of `\label{eq11}` to avoid auto-numeration of this line (more generally, add it to remove the number of any line)

Answer (score 9):

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
See the equations below:
\begin{subequations}
\label{all1}
 \begin{align}
  a & = b \label{eq1} \\
  c & = d \label{e2}
 \end{align}
\end{subequations}

These refer to \ref{all1}, \ref{eq1} and \ref{e2}.
\end{document}
```

The `amsmath` package introduces the `subequations` environment.  The first label, 'all1', before the `\begin{align}`, creates a label for the complete set of equations (1, in this case).  The two subsequent labels refer to 1a and 1b respectively.

Is that what you were asking about (the existence of the subequations environment, and numbering the composite equation distinctly from the subequations), or the `\eqref` part?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a somewhat old thread but I could not help to notice, that no one have suggested to use the gather-aligned combination when one has to referre to multiple equations that will always need to be referenced together:

```
    \begin{gather}
      \begin{aligned}
         a&= b\\
         c&= d
      \end{aligned}\label{eq:eq1}
    \end{gather}
    some text referring to \eqref{eq:eq1}
```

This will produce a reference to the set of equations and the reference number will be centered with respect to the equations.